# C++ : undetectable change of variable, artificial "volatile" mutex not works

Tags: c++, multithreading

How it is possible, that is such a line just after if statement with unequal, variables are already equal in pull() method? I have already added Mutex variable, but it not helped.

```
 int fQ::pull(void){ // pull element from the queue
  while(MutexF);
   MutexF = 1;
  if (last != first){
  fQueue[first++]();
  first%=lengthQ;
  MutexF = 0;
  return 0;
  }
  else{
      MutexF = 0;
        return 1;
  }
}
```

STL containers are to heavy for me, I preparing it for a tiny MCU, that's why, I tried to avoid   all this complex staff like (std::mutex, std::atomic, std::mutex etc.). Those  multitheading is needed only for test purpose, instead of testing with the tiny MCU's interrupts, for a while. I supposed not use any stl/thread libraries at all

[photo of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFNxx.png)

https://github.com/WeSpeakEnglish/nortos/blob/master/C_plus_plus_implementation/main.cpp

https://github.com/WeSpeakEnglish/nortos/blob/master/C_plus_plus_implementation/nortos.h

Comment: 1) Post errors as is, do not use screenshots. 2) you definitely don't understand multi-threaded programming - start with some toturials/books/guidelines about that. (`std::mutex`, `std::condition_variable` etc) 3) volatile is not about multithreading, it's about caching and compiler optimizations. You can use `std::atomic` for your example. 4) Why you don't use STL/Boost containers?

Comment: As a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning questions like the above, you also need to extract a [mcve] and provide that inline in your question. The reason external links are not suitable is that they point to resources that may change without notice, making the info that remains in your question unusable.

Comment: 4) Why you don't use STL/Boost containers? 
STL containers are to heavy for me, I preparing it for a tiny MCU, that's why, I tried to avoid   all this complex staff like (std::mutex, std::atomic, std::mutex etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you'd better use `std::atomic` and/or `std::mutex` for synchronization purposes. At least use `std::flag`. `volatile` has issues in general - it isn't suited for atomic operations - it has a different purpose altogether.

Second in your code, there is a bug and I don't know to solve it properly with `volatile`.

```
 while(MutexF);
 MutexF = 1;
```

Imagine, someone set `MutexF` to 0, then two threads simultaneously exited the while loop before setting `MutexF=1`. What do you think is gonna happen?

Perhaps you can synchronize two thread - one for pull and one for push in this manner - but you'd better abandon such approach.

Comment: Thanks, mutex and atomic solved the problem
class fQ {
private:
    std::atomic<int> first;
    std::atomic<int> last;
    FunctionPointer * fQueue;
    int lengthQ;
    std::mutex mtx;
public:
    fQ(int sizeQ);
    ~fQ();
    int push(FunctionPointer);
    int pull(void);
};

Answer (score 0):

```
   #include <mutex>          // std::mutex

typedef void(*FunctionPointer)(void);

class fQ {
private:
    std::atomic<int> first;
    std::atomic<int> last;
    FunctionPointer * fQueue;
    int lengthQ;
    std::mutex mtx;
public:
    fQ(int sizeQ);
    ~fQ();
    int push(FunctionPointer);
    int pull(void);
};

fQ::fQ(int sizeQ){ // initialization of Queue
  fQueue = new FunctionPointer[sizeQ];
  last = 0;
  first = 0;
  lengthQ = sizeQ;
}

fQ::~fQ(){ // initialization of Queue
  delete [] fQueue;
}

int fQ::push(FunctionPointer pointerF){ // push element from the queue
 mtx.lock();
  if ((last+1)%lengthQ == first){
        mtx.unlock();
        return 1;
  }
  fQueue[last++] = pointerF;
  last = last%lengthQ;
  mtx.unlock();
  return 0;
}

int fQ::pull(void){ // pull element from the queue
 mtx.lock();
  if (last != first){
  fQueue[first++]();
  first = first%lengthQ;
   mtx.unlock();
  return 0;
  }
  else{
   mtx.unlock();
   return 1;
  }
}
```